# Как делать запись в .txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, логирование, запись, txt

Суть в том, что я хочу записать какую-то фразу в файл. Например

```
a = 'test'
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(a)
```

В файле сохраняется test.

Но если я поменяю значение а:

`a = 'test_2'`

То в файле сохраняется test_2.

Как сделать так, чтобы к прошлому значению добавилось новое значение а?

Т.е. в файле будет:

test

test_2

Comment: Ну открывайте файл в режиме `'a'`, т.е. `append`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По ссылке ниже можете посмотреть все режимы открытия файла. Если вам нужно открыть файл на чтение и запись, попробуйте использовать режим "r+"

https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/fajly-rabota-s-fajlami.html